# What controls are "viewable" after scroll in panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a label array in a Windows Forms panel (up to 50 labels). When vertically scrolled the "viewable" indexes of the array - change. How can I get only the indexes of the now onscreen labels?

Comment: I think you need to calculate between the form's height and labels' heights (including padding n margins).

Comment: Use the label's Bounds and Intersect() it with the panel's DisplayRectangle.  Do avoid putting 50 labels in a panel, very wasteful.  That surely ought to be a ListBox or the panel's Paint event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach that converts the ClientRectangle of the Panel and each Label to screen coords and then checks for an intersection:

[image: Visbile Labels in Scrolled Panel]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private Label[] Labels;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Labels = new Label[] { label1, label2, label3, label4, label5 };
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> names = new List<string>(); // for demonstration purposes

        // determine which Labels are currently visible in the scrolled panel:
        Rectangle rectPanel = panel1.RectangleToScreen(panel1.ClientRectangle);
        for(int i = 0; i < Labels.Length; i++)
        {
            Rectangle rectLabel = Labels[i].RectangleToScreen(Labels[i].ClientRectangle);
            if (rectLabel.IntersectsWith(rectPanel))
            {
                // ... do something with "i" ...
                names.Add(Labels[i].Name); // for demonstration purposes
            }
        }

        listBox1.DataSource = null; // for demonstration purposes
        listBox1.DataSource = names; // for demonstration purposes
    }

}
```